# Closed Operator on a Sobolev space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

I am wondering if the following differential operator 
$A:D(A)( \subset {\bf{H}}) \to {\bf{H}}$ defined on the sobolev space $\mathbf{H}=H_{0}^{k}(0,1)\times {{L}^{2}}(0,1)\text{ }$ is a closed operator or not
\begin{align}
  & A(f,g)=(g,\frac{{{d}^{k}}f}{d{{x}^{k}}}) \\ 
 & D(A)=\left\{ (f,g)\in \mathbf{H}|A(f,g)\in \mathbf{H} \right\} \\ 
\end{align}

I do appreciate in advance if you help me with this; please give me the name of the Theorem which deals with the closeness of such an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a theorem to help you in this case.  However your operator is a sum of an inclusion from $L^2$ to $H_0^k$ in the first coordinate and a $k$th derivative into $L^2$ from $H^k$ in the second.  The differential part is in fact a bounded operator.  Therefore you only need to consider the inclusion.  I think you can verify directly that the inclusion is closed - it is not such a hard thing to do, since an inclusion has straightforward action.

Is what I am saying about the decomposition clear?

$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & I \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
\frac{d^k}{dx^k} & 0 \\
\end{array} \right)$$

Does this seem reasonable?  You have to be careful with the domains of sums of unbounded operators, but in this case since the one term is bounded you will be ok.

Comment: I was not convinced that how you concluded that the differential operator is a bounded operator. we can design lots of examples that show a differential operator between these two spaces is in fact unbounded. for example consider a function that has not a $k+1$th order weak derivatives, but it has $k$ order weak derivatives.

Comment: Yes, differential operators are not bounded typically.  However in this case $H^k$ just exactly gives you up to $k$ derivatives in $L^2$, and in fact $\| \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f \|_{L^2(0,1)} \leq \| f \|_{H^k_0(0,1)}$ for any $f \in H_0^k(0,1)$, simply by definition of the Sobolev norm.

Comment: Exactly, But how about the closeness. There are some examples which shows an operator is not bounded, but closed. However, in a Sobolev space the closeness is much more achievable, because of this I emphasis on Sobolev space.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely true.  In fact your operator $A$ is not bounded, for sure.  But you are trying to determine if it is closed.  From this standpoint it simplifies the issue to separate the bounded parts of the operator out, and then it turns out that the remaining part is easily seen to be closed I believe.

Comment: thank you, let me change the question to a more clear question. is a $k$th order differential operator in the Sobolev space $H^k_0$ a closed operator?

Comment: Sorry, my exposition was not good :)  Assuming you mean $A: H_0^k \rightarrow L^2$, yes, that operator is bounded.  

A more typical example would be, say, $A = - \Delta $ from $L^2$ to $L^2$ with domain $D(A) = H^2 \cap H_0^1$.  In this case the operator is not bounded.  The fact that we are going from a very smooth space ($H^k$) to a very unsmooth space ($L^2$) is important to your question.

Comment: Thanks, Got it, what I understood so far is that: the differential operator with this domain is bounded, and since it was densely defined thus it is closed operator indeed.

Comment: Hah I don't want to carry this too much further because the page is starting to yell at me about having a long comment discussion.  That is true for these particular problems that we have made up in the comments.  For your original problem $A$ is NOT bounded, but is closed.  I hope this was of some help to you!  Final addition - in your original $A$ it is not the differential part but the part that maps $g$ from $L^2$ to $H^k$ that makes it unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, in a book written by robinson, 2001, "infinite dimensional spaces and systems"

A $k$th order differential operator in the Sobolev space $H^k_0$ a closed operator.

Answer (score 0):

For the closeness you have to pay attention carefully to domains, an operator can be turned into closed operator only by changing the domain of definition.